# Custom Total Column in Power Bi Matrix

Tags: matrix, powerbi

Is there a way to show only one column with a measure (average, sum, percentage, etc.) at the end of the matrix in Power BI? I want to show the difference between 2019 and 2020 in sales.

[image]

Thanks.